# How can i get text content in a nested span?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

this is html and javascript code I was trying to create to get the value inside last span tag:

```js
var value2=$('#jsVal span .EmbeddedMiniatureVisualization')[0];

console.log(value2)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="jsVal">
<span id="36eb3c8a1503436b8b0a79ce1758d05a" style="">
    <span id="89e56665-5959-4e67-8fb8-83ca7cef9965" viewid="89e56665-5959-4e67-8fb8-83ca7cef9965" class="EmbeddedMiniatureVisualization" sf-busy="false" style="position: relative; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; overflow: hidden;">
        <span style="color: rgb(79, 79, 79); text-align: right;">53338060787</span>
    </span>
</span>
</div>
```

From developer tools, I see that it returns this:

```
<span id="89e56665-5959-4e67-8fb8-83ca7cef9965" viewid="89e56665-5959-4e67-8fb8-83ca7cef9965" class="EmbeddedMiniatureVisualization" sf-busy="false" style="position: relative; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; overflow: hidden;">
    <span style="color: rgb(79, 79, 79); text-align: right;">53338060787</span>
</span>
```

So from this, How can i get the text inside span? Is there a more straightforward way?

I tried this:

```
var value=$('div#jsVal span span.EmbeddedMiniatureVisualization span').text().trim();
```

but I get null value...

Comment: You did include jquery in your html right?

Comment: Yes, I Included it. Anyway I don't need to use jquery, solutions in vanilla javascript are welcome too!

Comment: @Porridge did you get your answer ?

Comment: @ZulqarnainJalil Yes. I had a problem with initial rendering of html. I had to wrap code in ```$("#jsVal").bind('DOMSubtreeModified',function(){})```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could ask for the last element that doesn't have a child, at any point.. so from the top

```
$("#jsVal :not(:has(*))").text();
```

or from anywhere below

```
$("#jsVal span.EmbeddedMiniatureVisualization :not(:has(*))").text();
```

Target the highest level at which you can guarantee it is what you want, by ID or Class

Comment: I tried your solution but it returns null value. If I write console.log($("#jsVal :not(:has(*))")); It returns this on developer tools: https://imgur.com/a/g2XLq8o. TextContent attribute with value "53338060787" is inside "0" sub-element.

Comment: you need to add `.text()`, so `console.log($("#jsVal :not(:has(*))").text());`

Comment: thanks, your solution works! I had a problem with initial rendering of html. I had to wrap it in ```$("#jsVal").bind('DOMSubtreeModified',function(){})```.

Answer (score 1):

You can use find like code given below

```js
//var val=$("#jsVal .EmbeddedMiniatureVisualization").find("span").text();
//var val = $("#jsVal .EmbeddedMiniatureVisualization span")[0].innerHTML // you can also use this
//var val =$($("#jsVal .EmbeddedMiniatureVisualization span")[0]).text() //you can also use this
var val=document.querySelector("#jsVal .EmbeddedMiniatureVisualization span:nth-child(1)").textContent; // for javascript
console.log(val)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="jsVal">
<span id="36eb3c8a1503436b8b0a79ce1758d05a" style="">
    <span id="89e56665-5959-4e67-8fb8-83ca7cef9965" viewid="89e56665-5959-4e67-8fb8-83ca7cef9965" class="EmbeddedMiniatureVisualization" sf-busy="false" style="position: relative; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; overflow: hidden;">
        <span style="color: rgb(79, 79, 79); text-align: right;">53338060787</span>
    </span>
</span>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, your solution works! I had a problem with initial rendering of html. I had to wrap your code in ```$("#jsVal").bind('DOMSubtreeModified',function(){})```.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are not fulling going to the element that you want in text format. I suggest to go deep and apply text to each element then only it will work.

See in the image I get two different `a=output` for each almost same query:

[image]

The first output I get is list of nan values

The second Output I get is the list of elements that I want.

See my `ipynb` file for your reference if you want.
[Here is the link](https://github.com/PullarwarOm/devtomanager.com-Web-Scraping/blob/main/devtomanager%20Final.ipynb)

Comment: Thanks for your reply but It seems a bit out of scope.

Comment: Give me the url ill try and tell me what you want to scrape.

Comment: I don't need to scrape anything and mostly I'm using javascript code. Thank you anyway.